# How to get Advertising id in android?

Tags: android

> I used this code it's working when i called from activity and fragment

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.Info;


Info adInfo = null;

try {
     adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(mContext);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

String AdId = adInfo.getId();
```

> But when i called from pending intent like Package Removed then i want to call the web service at that time i need advertising id but i got null.if you people had done previously please suggest me.thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of AAID in your app? Do you want to get the device unique ID which even does not change , when device is reboot?

Answer (score 1):

**try use app context**

as receivers could use activity context or app context - depends who&how started the receiver

```
 AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I have one doubt , please help me on that, How to get the unique ID of the user which can not change even wipe out data from the device, I heard about the "Advertisement ID", is it solve my problem, Please help me on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code and call the bellow method on onCreate

```
public void getAAID()
{
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(MyActivity.this);
                String myId = adInfo != null ? adInfo.getId() : null;

               Log.i("UIDMY",myId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("error", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Check complete post: [how to get AAID programmatically](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/get-android-advertisement-id-aaid-programmatically/)

Comment: Does AAID is unquie device ID, Does it change when device is reboot or reset or data wipe out?